# Google Calendar Zend_Loader errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm running into some errors with Zend_Loader (1.10.8) when I initialize the Google Calendar API in PHP. Here is my code:

```
\Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
\Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
\Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
$this->_service = \Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$this->_client  = \Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(USER, PASS, $this->_service);
$this->_client->setConfig(array('keepalive' => true));
$this->_service = new \Zend_Gdata_Calendar($this->_client);
$this->defaultQuery = $this->_service->newEventQuery();
```

That last line gives the following errors:

```
Warning: include_once(Zend/Gdata/Calendar/Extension/EventQuery.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/Calendar/Extension/EventQuery.php' for inclusion
```

This doesn't break any functionality, but I can't figure out how to resolve the errors. My EventQuery.php files lives in "/Zend/Gdata/Calendar/EventQuery.php" and not the path it's using in the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a bug**, and it seems it occurs again in newer versions of ZendFramework

here is the original http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7013?focusedCommentId=49379

here is the one i reopened but nothing happends http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11959

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you've registered an error handler which throws an Exception:

```
set_error_handler('errorFunction');

function errorFunction($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

In Zend/Gdata/App.php version 1.11.11, lines 1046 to 1059:

```
1046             foreach ($this->_registeredPackages as $name) {
1047                  try {
1048                      // Autoloading disabled on next line for compatibility
1049                      // with magic factories. See ZF-6660.
1050                      if (!class_exists($name . '_' . $class, false)) {
1051                         require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
1052                         @Zend_Loader::loadClass($name . '_' . $class);
1053                      }  
1054                      $foundClassName = $name . '_' . $class;
1055                      break;
1056                  } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
1057                      // package wasn't here- continue searching
1058                  }   
1059             }
```

The class relies on the loader to throw a Zend_Exception if the file / class it tries to load doesn't exist, or just suppresses the error with the `@` symbol.

Throwing the `ErrorException` in the error handler bypasses the error suppression, and causes this code to fail.

#### The Solution

I've commented on the ZF issue the reason and a potential fix for the problem. In the mean time, you can just add the following on lines 1058 - 1060

```
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    //Do Nothing, just the file not found error
}
```

**or** just change the `Zend_Exception` on line 1056 to the base `Exception`, as it's done in ZF2.

Comment: nice, but i the problem is i have an error handler that logs all the errors so that i can fix them later and having to remember to apply manually a patch everytime i upgrade zendframework is not so comfortable

Comment: Definitely. Hopefully the Zend guys will fix this soon. I checked the ZF2 code, and it's already fixed in there.

Comment: This error still shows in `1.12.1` which has the fix above in it.

Comment: @Withremote What exception is being thrown? And what's the exception message?

Comment: @Jrgns `error - 2013-02-19 13:19:25 --> Severity: Warning  --> include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/Calendar/Extension/EventQuery.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:www:/home/grchamb/public_html/mm/application/libraries') /home/grchamb/public_html/mm/application/libraries/Zend/Loader.php 134` but all the functions still work despite the include error. `Zend_Gdata_App_Exception` is returning no error.

Comment: @Withremote What you're reporting is an error, not an exception. This only applies if you convert errors into exceptions using code similar to that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm just getting the missing file error, no exception.