# Weird Zend Framework issue - include_once is looking in the wrong folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I've spent a lot of time troubleshooting this myself but none of what I've read solves my issue so I'm hoping I get some help here.

So anyway, I have written a PHP script that provides various functions to connect with Google Calendar. When I run this script directly using some inline test code to call my functions, everything runs fine. However, when I call the function from other scripts using 'require_once' to include it I get the following errors:

```
Warning: include_once(Zend\Gdata\Calendar\Extension\EventQuery.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Luke Franklin\Clients\Tiers For Tea\Development\TiersForTea.com v1.1\lib\Zend\Loader.php on line 134
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend\Gdata\Calendar\Extension\EventQuery.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\Users\Luke Franklin\Clients\Tiers For Tea\Development\TiersForTea.com v1.1\lib;C:\xampp\htdocs\TiersForTea.com\lib') in C:\Users\Luke Franklin\Clients\Tiers For Tea\Development\TiersForTea.com v1.1\lib\Zend\Loader.php on line 134
```

Your first thoughts might be that I'm not using the correct include path, but I have checked and rechecked this many times. I even tried hard coding the path. I'm quite sure that I'm using the correct path.

Now for the weird bit. If you look at the error you will notice the file Zend is trying to include: `Zend\Gdata\Calendar\Extension\EventQuery.php`. This file does not actually exist in the 'Extension' folder. It does exist in the parent folder though. If I just copy 'EventQuery.php' into the 'Extension' folder my script runs as expected. Weird, right?

So that does sorta solve my problem, but I would like to know what's going on here in-case it creates further issues. I should also note that I'm calling this script into an OpenCart module.

You might want to see some of my code so here's a snippet of the important bits, if you want more details just let me know:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath('\\lib') . PATH_SEPARATOR . "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\TiersForTea.com\\lib");
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');

function connect() {
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
```

Comment: Sounds like one of the Zend files has an incorrect path to `EventQuery.php`. What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: It does seem that way but it's unusual that this script works fine on its own in testing but not when included by other PHP scripts. My version of Zend is 1.12.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Calendar Zend\_Loader errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438715/google-calendar-zend-loader-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt the error exists in any of the Zend files as you have indicated it works correctly in your isolation tests.

The error is thrown from `Zend_Loader` which means something in your code is making reference to `Zend_Gdata_Calendar_Extension_EventQuery`.

Check the stack trace for the error if available to pinpoint the location. If that's not available, do a global find for that string. If you find any matches, you will need to change them to `Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventQuery`.

### Update

Seems this is a known bug(s)

- http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7013
- http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11959

It's an issue when your code registers an error handler using `ErrorException`. Apparently it's fixed in the 1.12 branch but hasn't made it to a release yet.

There's a patch in the 11959 bug report that fixes the issue

Comment: Thanks for the response Phil. I couldn't find the string in any of my files.

Comment: @LukeFranklin Can you search through all the files (Zend, OpenCart and anything else you're using)?

Comment: I create an EventQuery object like so: `$query = $dataSource->newEventQuery();`

$dataSource comes from the connect function as per my original snippet.  Like so: `new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client)`

Comment: I searched everything. 0 results for "Zend_Gdata_Calendar_Extension_EventQuery"